# Jackson ObjectMapper default property order

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

Does anyone know if there is a specific default order of properties when serialising an object to JSON with ObjectMapper (ie in the absence of any specific sort order configuration or `@JsonPropertyOrder` annotations?

I haven't found anything yet in the documentation. I can check the source code, but thought I would quickly check here first - I'm guessing it is based on whatever ordering comes from reflection or introspection, and this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/jackson-user/VZhiGEoyPBM) I found from a while ago suggests that there are no guarantees on ordering (again I can check source but it would be great if somebody just happens to know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post is still up-to-date. Default order depends from given implementation (aka version). You need to check implementation:

- In `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect` package, e.g.: `POJOPropertiesCollector` class.
- In `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser` package, e.g.: `BeanSerializer`, `BeanSerializerFactory` classes.
- Used annotations, e.g.: `JsonIgnore`.

Also it depends from:

- Enabled features, e.g.: [REQUIRE_SETTERS_FOR_GETTERS](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#REQUIRE_SETTERS_FOR_GETTERS)
- Enabled modifiers, e.g.: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerModifier` class.

From [other side](https://www.json.org/json-en.html):

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

And you should not depend on it.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this documentation](https://tedblob.com/jackson-serialization-order/), By default, the ordering of the fields in the serialized JSON depends on the JDK. It may be the declaration order but not guaranteed.